# trying to copy files with certain extensions into another folder using shutil.copy

Tags: python, copy, shutil

I am trying to copy files with certain extensions into another folder but when I am trying to copy them I get just 12 text files while I have lots of more files that I did not copy.
this is the code :

```
import shutil
from malware import*
import os
for dirpath , dirname , filenames in os.walk(r'D:\\'):
        for file in filenames:
            full_dir = dirpath+file
            if file.endswith(tuple(ex_list)):
                try:
                    shutil.copy(full_dir, r'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\beef')
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    pass
```

and this is the list of extensions:

```
ex_list = {".PDF" ,
           "pdf" ,
           ".txt" ,
           ".doc" ,
           ".docx" ,
           ".png"
           }
```

I have tried to change shutil.copy into shutil.copy2 or shutil.copyfile but nothing worked.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code at all? For example, did you try to check what values of `full_dir` are created, and which ones are passed to `shutil.copy`?

Comment: (Also: please do not tag 3.x and 2.x by default; the 3.x tag is effectively useless now, and the 2.x tag should *only* be used if you *must* use a 2.x version of Python to solve your problem, *even knowing* that it is *over two years* past its EOL date.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try doing `any` over all of the potential extensions:

```
if any(file.endswith(extension) for extension in ex_list):
```

Note that `ex_list` is actually a set (and thus the name is a bit of a misnomer). You might instead write `ex_list = [...]` for it to be a list (though this is not necessary). Also, unless you are doing work concurrently, `FileNotFoundError` should never be found in an `os.walk` and in fact, I believe it is being raised because you are not giving the full path to the file. Try this instead:

```
shutil.copy(os.path.join(dirpath, dirname, filename), r'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\beef')
```

Whenever you are joining filenames, and directories, I would recommend using `os.path.join`. This ensures that the proper separators appear regardless of the operating system.